# How to get data from several days after certain hour of each day?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, select

I am working on some reports about Sales given certain times, I have managed to get the sum of the sales given the day of the week, but i need further narrowing, I need to get the sum of each day of the week sales, that are made after 13:00.

This is the code used for getting the sum of the sales per day of the week

```
SELECT 
sum(ammount), datename (weekday,sale_date)
FROM SALES where sale_date > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
group by datename (weekday,sale_date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a condition for "after 13:00" to the `where` clause:

```
where   sale_date > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
        and datepart(hour, sale_date) >= 13
```

Comment: Given this result, and asking also the <13, then adding it to the previous, I get a far bigger sum(ammount) thant the original query. How can that be?

Comment: Daily sales = sales before 13 + sales on or after 13:00.  If you get a different result, you're probably using a wrong query.

Comment: Solved it, I accidentally read the sales on Saturday, and added to Monday, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `hh` part of [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)?

```
SELECT Sum(ammount), 
       Datename (weekday, sale_date) 
FROM   sales 
WHERE  sale_date > '2012-01-01 00:00:00' 
       AND Datepart(hh, sale_date) >= 13 
GROUP  BY Datename (weekday, sale_date)
```

Comment: and how can I add this on the where clause?

Comment: Thanks, of course your answer is also right, I just gave the accepted answer to Andomar because he kind of posted it faster and ready on a complete answer form.